# Windows Service rundll32.exe always listening on port8080, even when stopped

Tags: windows-10, port, services, tomcat

I have a problem when i start my Java application by Spring (using tomcat), the port 8080 is allready listening by a service, which is "rundll32.exe", apparently a legitime file from system32, but even when i kill it, it come back, here is my prompt commands:

```
tasklist | findstr 15448
rundll32.exe                 15448 Services                   0     56,592 K

netstat -ano | findstr 8080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15448

taskkill /F /pid 15448
SUCCESS: The process with PID 15448 has been terminated.

netstat -ano | findstr 8080
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       9796

tasklist | findstr 9796
rundll32.exe                  9796 Services                   0     55,976 K
```

As you can see, the service always listening the port8080. I tried to search a solution but i did not find a similar problem on the internet. Have you any suggestion? (I stoped then killed the rundll32 process in the Services list, but nothing has change)

I have to kill this listening because i work with Tomcat and Spring (for Java developpement) which are using this port by default. The other solution will be to change the port number used by tomcat, but it's kind of a convention to use 8080 as default port for standard projects.

[Here is the details in the Process explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sze76.jpg)

Comment: So does this prevent your application from starting/working?

Comment: The problem is that i work with Tomcat and Spring (for Java developpement) which are using this port by default. The other solution will be to change the port number used by tomcat, but it's kind of a convention to use 8080 as default port for standard projects.

Comment: If you use a tool like Process Explorer to view the processes in a tree view, what is the parent process of the rundll32.exe process and what are the command line arguments to it?

Comment: The parent seems to be a svchost.exe, you can see the details on the link i added on the bottom of the Question above.

Answer (score 0):

`rundll32.exe` is a legitimate Windows file, but it can be used for malicious purposes. It's an executable that can run code from any `.dll` file, not necessarily a harmless one.

You've already determined that this process is owned by `svchost.exe`, which is also a core Windows file, but can be used to run malicious code. It's a service host, each and every Windows service uses it to run. But again, non-Microsoft services can be registered and it's by design.

So we have to find out what service is running on that host. Find the correct `svchost.exe` in Task Manager on the *Details* tab (you can pinpoint that specific svchost by its PID), right-click it and select *Go to service(s)*. Services running on that host will be highlighted. From this point we can continue to check if it's something harmless or malware.

Port 8080 is pretty common for running various servers, mostly HTTP, but there are exceptions - for example Skype will run on this port unless it's disabled in settings.